# How to prevent YouTube from showing already watched videos?

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to prevent YouTube from showing videos already watched in the list of suggested videos?

Comment: A quick glance at the HTML makes me think that it shouldn't be _too_ hard to do. You basically want to set `display: none` on any `<ytd-compact-video-renderer>` element that contains a child element `#progress`. You won't be able to do that in CSS, but a Tampermonkey script should be simple enough. I'll have a go later and write an answer...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently, there is no treat/workaround to do so. Apart from manually block them one by one, there are no scalable solutions.

[image: 0]

But there are extensions which can do so like:

- Chrome extension: **[Subscriptions Grid For YouTube™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/subscriptions-grid-for-yo/dcnjhgnfnmijfkmcddcmffeamphmmeed?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)**
- Chrome extension: **[YouTweak for YouTube™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtweak-for-youtube-subs/cfgpigllcihcpkbokdnmpkjobnebflgh)**
- Chrome extension: **[YouTube Watched](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-watched/dckoecgnbnmbgjchiopfbjkpemkmllbj)**
- Chrome extension: **[Better Tube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-tube/akbfgdngmldgocljaonhjnmnffdagpdl)**
- Chrome extension: **[Better Subscriptions for YouTube™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-subscriptions-for/fkchdogohkjpnhfkganifkbbjcjofbjf?hl=en)** - ([@Ashley](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/213146/))
- JS UserScript: **[YouTube: Hide Watched Videos](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/13040-youtube-hide-watched-videos/code)**

---

```
// ==UserScript==
// @version        1.1.1
// @name           Hide watched videos on YouTube
// @namespace      https://gist.github.com/xPaw/6324624
// @match          https://www.youtube.com/*
// @updateURL      https://gist.github.com/xPaw/6324624/raw/YoutubeHideWatched.user.js
// @downloadURL    https://gist.github.com/xPaw/6324624/raw/YoutubeHideWatched.user.js
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==

const app = document.querySelector( 'ytd-app' );

function HideVideos( a )
{
    app.querySelectorAll( 'ytd-thumbnail-overlay-resume-playback-renderer:not([data-hidden="true"])' ).forEach( element =>
    {
        element.dataset.hidden = true;

        while( ( element = element.parentNode ).tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'ytd-item-section-renderer' )
        {
            // Find the container element for this video
        }

        element.hidden = true;
    } );
}

function ProcessPage()
{
    if( !window.location.pathname.startsWith( '/feed/subscriptions' ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    const list = app.querySelector( 'ytd-section-list-renderer' );

    if( list.dataset.hooked )
    {
        return;
    }

    list.dataset.hooked = true;
    list.addEventListener( 'yt-next-continuation-data-updated', HideVideos );

    // TODO: Find an event to fix this
    new MutationObserver( HideVideos ).observe( list, { childList: true, subtree: true } );
}

app.addEventListener( 'yt-navigate-finish', ProcessPage );

ProcessPage();
```

Comment: That's a shame. I'm getting the same ~dozen music videos all the time but completely blocking them is overkill.

Comment: oh nice, you updated with a userscript! :-)

Comment: Some don't work, but this is what I was looking for.  Tks

Comment: Of the Chrome extensions "Better Subscriptions for YouTube" is the only one that still exists / has recent updates. It worked for me, though, and there are also >15 other plugins in the "related" list on the plugins.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, there's no way to do this on YouTube itself, but I use a Chrome extension ([Better Subscriptions for YouTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-subscriptions-for/fkchdogohkjpnhfkganifkbbjcjofbjf?hl=en)) that lets you hide watched videos from your subscriptions tab.

Answer (score 3):

I have developed a professional add-on/user script specialy for hiding watched videos on YouTube:
watched videos hider addon for Firefox
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-watched-videos-hider/

for chrome and other browsers you need to use the user script limited edition, becouse she will hide also your YouTube songs play list but the addon have option to solve that, you can just stop the script when you want to listen to prewatched song

Firstly you need to install the user script manager

> > https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en
> >     https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/tampermonkey-beta/

Then install the user script from this GitHub link, it should automatically installed with one click , otherwise you need to copy the script and past it in the user script manager(like temper monkey)

> > https://github.com/ibtisammidlet/youtube-watched-videos-hider/raw/master/youtube-watched-videos-hider.user.js

Comment: Okay thanks for head up, I have improved my answare now.

Comment: Why would that plugin need my Youtube ID for anything? Somehow I can only think of sinister reasons. It shouldn't be necessary for detecting watched videos. Watched video thumbnails have a timeline overlayed on them which you can detect.

Comment: Thanks--this hides them (tested in Chrome) but doesn't prevent auto-play from playing them. (Which of course would be asking for a lot). As expected [though not desired per se], it hides partially-watched videos and sometimes makes YouTube a little "glitchy" in loading video thumbnails

Comment: Your plugin still shows watched videos by Shift+n (next video) and in playlist in full mode (left upper corner)

Answer (score 1):

This is by far the best solution I have for the problem.

Install [uBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) on your Firefox or Chrome and add the following filter rule on Options -> My Filters.

```
! removes watched video items
www.youtube.com###dismissible:has(#progress.ytd-thumbnail-overlay-resume-playback-renderer)
```

Note that it also blocks watched videos across the website, on the search page, uploaded by a user page. If you need to block for example only on the right bar suggestion area when you're on a video, add a path filter in the filter rule.

```
www.youtube.com##:matches-path(/^/watch/) #dismissible:has(#progress.ytd-thumbnail-overlay-resume-playback-renderer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension like [YouTube Hider](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/show-no-more-watched-yout/jiodfiiphdgcnmpfdhpjnpijndmkidkj)